# Tailwind cssでJITによる逐次コンパイルの方法

Tags: laravel, tailwindcss

以前からTailwind cssを使っていましたが、今回v2.2をインストールしてJITで逐次コンパイルを試みています。

`tailwind.config.js`にJIT設定(mode: 'jit')をして`npm run watch`で確かにapp.cssの容量が大幅に小さくなり動作は確認しました。
が、vscodeで例えば`text-gray-500`から`text-red-500`に変更しても逐次コンパイルされません。
`tailwind.config.js`をいじるか`npm run watch`を起動し直せばコンパイルされます。

ソースを変更したらリアルタイムでコンパイルされる様子をtwitterなどでいくつも見ているので、おそらく何かが足りないと思うのですが、どのようにしたらよいでしょうか。

追記
phpのlaravelを使っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm run watch` がどのようなコマンドを実際に実行しているかご質問に記載がないので、不明ですが、よくやるありそうなミスとしては

[【Tailwind CSS #5】開発が超ラクになるTailwindのJITモードを紹介！！ - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfR_0zbjKOM&t=180s)

この動画の３分から５分あたりの解説にある通り、

`TAILWIND_MODE=watch` と `-w`

の付け忘れだと思います。

公式ドキュメントだと
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#styles-don-t-update-when-saving-content-files
が該当箇所です。

`package.json`の該当箇所を確認してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。TAILWIND_MODE=watchを追加することで逐次コンパイルできるようになりました。
(watchモードは既に指定されていました)。
最初はどう追加して良いかわからず、いろんなサイトや公式で出てくる例をコピペしたり修正したりしてもうまくいかず随分遠回りしてしまいました。
結果的にlaravelをインストールしたときに作成されたpackage.jsonのコマンド部分に教えて頂いたTAILWIND_MODE=watchを追加するだけでした。
ありがとうございました！